# CodeIgniter - move database element

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm new to CodeIgniter, and to PHP overall and I need help with one task. I have to create method which will move a database element from one place to another inside one table.

This is my db:

```mysql
CREATE TABLE test (
  section_id bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  section_left bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  section_right bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  section_name varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Few example queries:

```mysql
INSERT INTO `test` (`section_id`, `section_left`, `section_right`, `section_name`)
VALUES
    (1,1,90,'Root'),
    (2,2,3,'HOME'),
    (197,42,43,'Autism Spectrum Disorder'),
    (198,44,45,'Asperger Syndrome'),
    (196,41,46,'Experiencing Disability'),
```

Now to the point: I need to create a method which will allow me to move element from one place to another by changing it's ID.
I'd like it to look something like this:

```php
move_element($elment_section_id, $destionation_section_id)
```

For example controller should look like this:

```php
move_element(223, 196)
```

The problem is that I really have no idea how my model function should look. Anyone can help and point me into right solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a method to move element by changing its ID then you are looking for an `update` statement in the model function.

```
move_element($elment_section_id, $destionation_section_id) {

    // sql this function needs to execute is:
    // "update `test` set `section_id` = $destionation_section_id where `section_id` = $elment_section_id";

    // in codeigniter, you can do something like this :
    $this->db->set('section_id', $destionation_section_id); // destination place
    $this->db->where('section_id', $elment_section_id); // original place
    $this->db->update('test');  //table name`
}
```

I hope, I've understood your question correctly. If not, kindly comment, I'd be happy to help.

Comment: Hi thanks for such a fast reply.
However this doesn't really work for me. I didn't mention this but it's in a nested set model. So what I wanted to get is:
- get all information about the element (section_id, section_left, section_right and section_name),
- then run the function move_element($elment_section_id, $destination_section_id) so it can change its' section_ID AND automaticly change the other sections for those which are connected with $destionation_section_id except name.
So for my example: move_element(197, 196) would give me a result: (196,41,46, 'Autism Spectrum Disorder')